# Uploading a photo to the vk.com api server

Tags: c#, vk

I'm trying to upload an image to the server of vk.com, but in result of my request -  I get an empty "photo":"[]";

`{"server":627329, "photo":"[]","hash":"6ce9e707ba60a464bc45070a748dc9ec "}`

my code is:

```
private static HttpWebResponse PostMethod()
    {

    //getting json with url to upload.
    string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getMessagesUploadServer?&v=5.31&access_token=247878418f7f0ab793cd40e1434af3f51794ec09e85";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string json = client.DownloadString(url);
    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    //getting an image for uploading later.
    byte[] imageData = client.DownloadData("http://cs5530.vk.me/u43529379/-6/m_b9515ce2.jpg");
    RootObject response = (RootObject)json_serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(RootObject));

    //Geting out url for uploading, from response.
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(response.response.upload_url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

    var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(imageData.ToString());

    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    using (var newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
      newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
      newStream.Close();
    }
      return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: trying to follow what's going on here, so are you download an image from a server then trying to upload it elsewhere?  maybe commenting a little more what you expect the various aspects of your code to do might help make it more clear

Comment: What does `imageData.ToString()` give you? And why are you calling `GetBytes` on a byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing the documentation you posted

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(response.response.upload_url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.TransferEncoding = "utf8";

UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
string postData = "photo=" + encoded;

request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
request.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(postData);

using (var newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    newStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    newStream.Close();
}
return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: thank you for an advice, but still getting "photo":"[]"

Comment: yes, I get json result {"server":627329, "photo":"[]","hash":"6ce9e707ba60a464bc45070a748dc9ec "},  content type should be "multipart/form-data", but it doesn't help me too.

Comment: Here are two steps, that i should do. https://vk.com/dev/photos.getMessagesUploadServer and after, https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveMessagesPhoto